# Linux LS command does not work correctly with * regular expression quantifier

Tags: linux, ubuntu

If I have a directory structure

```
~/foo/foo1
~/foo/foo2
~/foo/foo3
```

The output of following commands if I issue them from terminal in ~/foo:

1. `ls *foo1*` returns total of 0 directories
2. `ls *foo*` returns 3 directories foo1, foo2 and foo3
3. `ls` returns 3 directories foo1, foo2 and foo3
4. `ls -d *foo1*` returns foo1
5. `ls | grep *foo1*` returns foo1

Why does command 1. `ls *Foo1*` does not return Foo1?

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know why you're adding `*` around all of your names. You'd get the same results with `ls -l foo2`, `ls -d foo1`, `ls | grep foo1`, etc.

Comment: My question is the regex should work. Right? I know the alternatives.

Comment: None of your commands use regular expressions. All of your commands "work"; you haven't explained what you think is wrong with the output you're seeing.

Comment: Read carefully [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). Shell wildcard patterns are totally unrelated to [regex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html)s and have a different syntax. So `ls` was never meant to deal with regular expressions. Notice that wildcard expansion happens in the shell and programs like `ls` don't do them.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this explains it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really confused and you don't understand well the role of any [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell).

Read carefully about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), notably [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). It is not related to regular expressions (explained in [regex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html)). The `*` has very different role and meaning in shell wildcard patterns and in regular expressions. (So your mention of "regular expression" in your title is wrong).

The globbing happens in the shell, *before* running any program (or even any builtin command like `echo`). Read carefully the [documentation of `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/), its section on [shell operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html),  and the chapter on [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions).

The [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) program (that is, `/bin/ls`, because `/bin/` is in your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))) never sees any `*` or any wildcard file pattern in your case.

So you are typing `ls *foo*`. To understand what happens, type an `echo` in front, so type the command `echo ls *foo*`.  You'll get the expansion done by your shell. And the `/bin/ls` program is getting that expansion (at [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) time done inside the shell after a [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)).

BTW I prefer (for interactive usage) the [`zsh`](http://zsh.org/) shell to `bash` for its nicer [auto-completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete) abilities (and you might also try [`fish`](http://fishshell.com/)). I just type `ls *foo*` followed by the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, and my `zsh` interactive shell expands `*foo*` immediately and edit the command line. If I am happy with that expansion, I then just press the <kbd>return</kbd> key and the command line gets parsed and executed by my `zsh` shell. If that expansion is not what I want, `zsh` allows me to edit the command line.

This command expansion is not specific to `ls`. Any program started by the shell had its argument list obtained by shell expansions. In some occasions, you might use [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) instead of [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) (and *your* shell might have defined [aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html), so your `ls` could be an alias for something else).

Because of the way shell expansion work, I advise not having space or special characters (like control characters and newlines, or even `*` or `?`) in file names. However, you could use [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) techniques if you want to deal with file paths with strange names.

See also Yann Regis-Gianas excellent FOSDEM2018 talk on [*Parsing Posix [S]hell*](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/code_parsing_posix_s_hell/)

PS. Other OSes work differently. For Windows (which I don't know and never used) it is rumored that command expansion happens *inside* programs (in some [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) equivalent).

Comment: Perhaps also point to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs which explains some of the corner cases in more detail.

Comment: @tripleee: That page is interesting, but I feel it is not what the OP is asking. Parsing `ls` output is relevant for pipeline commands, and the OP's question don't mention them.

Comment: Absolutely; but it also explains e.g. how `ls` behaves differently in various situations, such as when it receives a directory argument (without `-d`).

Comment: To understand what a command like `ls` does I strongly recommend reading first the documentation of that command, that is the [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) man page.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the shell file glob (which, btw. is something different from a regular expression), which is working as expected (see `echo *foo*`, `echo *foo1*`) and everything with the way ls handles its arguments.

1. `ls *foo1*` expands to `ls foo1` in your case. this DOES list the *contents* of the directory, which apparently is empty in your case.
2. `ls -d *foo1*` expands to `ls -d foo1` in your case. this lists the foo1 directory *itself* instead of its contents.
3. `ls *foo*` lists the empty *contents* of all the foo* directories. this results in output of the directory names, even if they are empty. these are headers that ls creates only when more than one directory is to be listed.

Further reading:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ls -d` does not list the contents of directories.

Comment: right, sorry, that was a typo.